# Im new to react and I am having a ton of issues trying to get data fields from firestore to show up on the screen on my app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am going to include photos as well as my code. I do not know what I am doing wrong but I wanna be able to print the current user's name on their profile page as shown in pictures. Thanks so much! It seems as if it is never getting to the snapshot to try to retrieve the fields to where they can be used. I've been stuck on this for going on a week now and do not know what else to try. I feel like it is an easy fix that I am missing but cannot pinpoint what it is.

Firestore picture

[image: img_firestore]

App picture

[image: img_app]

```
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import auth, {firebase} from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
//import * as React from 'react';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Picker,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Profile = ({navigation}) => {
  const [firstName, setFname] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLname] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [age, setAge] = useState('');
  const [sex, setSex] = useState('');
  const [id, setId] = useState('');

  getUserInfo = async () => {
     firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .onSnapshot((docs) => {
        setFname(docs.data().firstName);
        console.log(firstName);
        setLname({lastName: docs.data().lastName});
        setEmail({email: docs.data().email});
        setPassword({password: docs.data().password});
        setAge({age: docs.data().age});
        setSex({sex: docs.data().sex});
        setId({id: docs.data().id});
      });
  };

  

  const db = firebase.firestore();
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var usersEmail = user.email;
  var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;


  
  
  db.collection('users')
    .where('email', '==', usersEmail)
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        var data = doc.data();
        const fn = doc.get('firstName');
        setFname({firstName: fn});
        console.log(firstName);
        console.log(data);
        setFname(data.firstName);
        //var lastName = data.lastName;
        //var firstName = doc.get("first");
        //var lastName = doc.get("last");
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });

    
    
 

  return (
    
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container2}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.logo}>Profile</Text>
          <Text style={styles.Info}>
            Name: {firstName} {lastName}  
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Info}>Email: {usersEmail}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.Info}>Age: </Text>
          <Text style={styles.Info}>Sex:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.Info}>Sports:</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EditProfile')}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Edit Profile</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Messages')}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>My Messages</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#2c9f45',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  container2: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#2c9f45',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    width: '85%',
    backgroundColor: '#263844',
    borderRadius: 25,
    height: 54,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  logo: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 54,
    color: '#263844',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  Info: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 22,
    color: '#263844',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default Profile;
```

Comment: Can you share what  you get in the logs?

Comment: Please provide some logs as mentioned by @Satheeshwaran. Or please consider creation of simple example according to  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Its all getting render before the results have been returned, you need include `useEffect` and run your firebase from within inside the useEffect function.

[This](https://medium.com/@gilshaan/react-native-hooks-how-to-use-usestate-and-useeffect-3a10fd3e760c) is pretty decent blog and will help with the understanding of hooks.

Something like this (untested);

```
 import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import auth, {firebase} from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
//import * as React from 'react';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Picker,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Profile = ({navigation}) => {
  const [firstName, setFname] = useState('');
  
 // const db = firebase.firestore();
 // const { email } = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const email = ‘Sprint3@test.com’;

useEffect( () => {
  db.collection('users')
    .where('email', '==', usersEmail)
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      // This will step over every doc that has that email, you should limit it one and organise by an updated field. .limit(1)
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        const fn = doc.get('firstName');
        setFname(fn);
        
       // Add whatever states from the data you need or just one object with all the info in.
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });
}, []);
    
    

  return (
    
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container2}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.logo}>Profile</Text>
          <Text style={styles.Info}>
            Name: {firstName} 
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EditProfile')}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Edit Profile</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Messages')}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>My Messages</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#2c9f45',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  container2: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#2c9f45',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    width: '85%',
    backgroundColor: '#263844',
    borderRadius: 25,
    height: 54,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  logo: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 54,
    color: '#263844',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  Info: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 22,
    color: '#263844',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default Profile;
```

Comment: Even after switching to useEffect, it does not seem to be getting the value firstName when trying to put it on the screen. I put his above the return function correct? and then should be able to call 'firstName' in the return function? or am i still doing something wrong?

Comment: useEffect should be above the return but within the exported function. I'll expand on my answer to help.

Comment: Thats how i have it and it seems to be having the exact same problem as before where it renders before the results are being returned. I am not sure what is causing this.

Comment: check my answer now, also check this post (this maybe a duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856233/cannot-display-data-from-firestore-in-react-app/64861830#64861830)

Comment: You’ll need to debug the code, but I notice you have a capitalised sting for the email in the doc, I don’t think that will help. I’ve hard coded the email address in see what happens now. Replace the currentUser and debug once you get it working. Without seeing your errors or logs can’t help any more!