# How can I query firestore within an react map iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm iterating over a collection in a react component.
For each line of this tab, I need to make an additional query to firebase:

```
         <Tbody>
          {households?.map((household) => (
            <Tr key={household.id}>
              <Td>{household.name}</Td>
              <Td>{household.ownerName}</Td>
              <Td>
                <ul>
                  {household.participants.map((participant) => (
                    <li key={participant.userId}>{participant.userName}</li>
                  ))}
                  //Here I need to retrieve another collection from firestore, which is different for each household.
                </ul>
              </Td>
              <Td>
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Tbody>
```

But I can't find how.

I tried this:

```
  {
    let invitesRef = collection(
      db,
      "households",
      household.id,
      "invites"
    );
    invitesRef.onSnapshot((invite) => {
      <li key={invite}>{invite}</li>
    })
    return <div></div>;
  }
```

But I get unexpected token, also it doesn't seems to like the const, ... So I'm probably on the wrong road.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In your second code sample, you never actually executed a query.  All you did was create a collection reference.  You can execute a query as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) using the `query` function to create a query object for a collection, followed by a call to `get`, which returns a promise that resolves with the matching documents for that query.

Comment: After that, if you want to perform multiple queries on multiple collections, you can do that in a loop *before* the JSX, await all the promises from all the queries, collect all that resulting data into an object, and provide that to your JSX to simplify things. Doing all that inside the `map` will make your job a lot harder given all the promises in play.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call asynchronous APIs during the rendering of your UI and then expect to use those results right in that code. No UI framework that I know off supports that.

In React, you instead will want to:

1. Start loading the data when your component first renders.
2. Show a "data is loading..." indicator while the data is loading.
3. Set the data to the state when the data is loaded.
4. Which then triggers a re-render of the UI, where you can use the data from the state.

I recommend reading up on:

- ReactJS state in [State: A Component's Memory](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory)
- [Using effects](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects) to handle step 1
- My answer to [cannot display data from firestore in react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64856233/cannot-display-data-from-firestore-in-react-app/64861573#64861573), which shows an example of the approach I explain above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do retrieve the initial list of household in an async way. But I don't know what I should do, for each of those results, make a second async request, complete the initial data(or store them somewhere else) and be sure they are still reactive when a change come.

Comment: That's an implementation choice. For some cases I wait for all data to completely load before setting it to the state (and triggering a re-render), but for other cases I update the state after every load (and thus re-render repeatedly) and show the progress. Either is fine, it just depends on your use-case and preference.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I'm not talking about rendering, I'm talking about how to get async data, for each element of another data I also did get in an async way and make sure that if I change something in firebase backend, it also gets updated in my list(like the other data from firebase)

Comment: There too it's an implementation choice: you can use a one-time get, or a realtime listener. In the latter case, you'll typically end up needing to track your active listeners, so you can [detach them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) when they're no longer needed.

Comment: Do you mind sharing an example with the two level of listener?